# Read a vb.net dll array into my main project

Tags: vb.net, dll

I wrote a vb.net DLL.  DLL work fine and create a set of variables in an array

How to read the array from the main project who is calling the dll?

```
Example
   Tmp0(1) = Dg(5)   'Urb
   Tmp0(2) = Dg(6)   'Line 1
   Tmp0(3) = Dg(7)   'Line 2
   Tmp0(4) = Dg(100) 'Type of unit

  ''This is calling the DLL
   Dim direccion As New DirStd.DirScr(Tmp0)
   direccion.ShowDialog() 

  'The Tmp0 array goes fine to the DLL

  'but when I read it 
   Tmp0(9) = direccion.getDir()
```

I got no new values, only the ones that I have sent

Help Please

ariel

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
   Dim direccion As New DirStd.DirScr(Tmp0)
   direccion.ShowDialog() 

   direccion.getDir(Tmp0)
   b = Tmp0(1)
   b1 = Tmp0(2)
   b2 = Tmp0(3)
   b3 = Tmp0(4)
```

in the DLL

```
    Public Function getDir(ntmp())
        For i As Integer = 1 To 9 : ntmp(i) = dirV(i) : Next
        Return ntmp(9)
    End Function
```